# How do I hide "Browse Page Publish" links to anonymous visitors in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The question is in the subject, but understand when I sign in I always want to see these features.

There is also another huge security issue with anonymous visitors in sharepoint , the settings wheel at the top right lets you go to site contents, and lets you see all items with peoples names when they checked in and etc, very odd that all options are hidden except that one.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SPSecurityTrimmedControl** tag to hide desired options from the ribbon to only specific permission levels. Simply surround that part of the ribbon with this tag which you want to hide.

You can view below given link for more details about SPSecurityTrimmedControl and its usage.

http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/Comments.aspx?ArticleId=28

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, didn't trust google with all the SP 2010 stuff around.  Never use the designer but guess I had to.  They really should make this an option.  I am also going to have to SEO this site and add meta tags and such so I guess im going to have to get used to it.

Comment: Yes buddy. SP Designer is for customization. You should get used to it :)